# Does python create a new List after 'del' in used on an element of the List?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, processing-efficiency, del

I plan to use an array as a stack for a binary tree print operation. Will it be more efficient to use Del operator to delete a node object from the list when it is printed, or sould I substitute some check symbol instead of the node object?

Is del operation efficient? After del operation does python still store the list contagiously?

It is an efficieny question.

Comment: Yes, the list is always stored contiguously. For this reason, using `del` or `pop` to remove elements from a list is rather unefficient, unless the element happens to be at the end of the list.

Comment: But if you're using the list as a stack, then you should always only be popping the last element, so there shouldn't be a problem. In that case, I recommend using a syntax like `l.pop()` rather than `del l[i]`; `l.pop()` without arguments will always pop the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Python List is perfect candidate for using it as a stack.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).